# Does the OEM video play after an ordinary OEM install?

Tags: boot, video, oem

I am giving an Ubuntu PC with an OEM install to my mom to convince her that Ubuntu is actually useful for "regular users", and I want the first boot video from Dell's Ubuntu machines to play when she boots up an OEM'd laptop for the first time. Does the OEM install do this automatically? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FeqfxttHPmA

Answer (score 1):

No it doesn't, at least not with 14.04

You can try it for yourself. Here is a how to.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Ubuntu_OEM_Installer_Overview